# Update exsiting Azure App Service in Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-web-app-service, terraform-provider-azure

I would like to update my exsiting Azure App Service in Terraform by adding a Backup to this App Service.
For now it looks like this:

```
data "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
  name                = "MyUniqueServicePlan"
  resource_group_name = "example-resources"
}


resource "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
  name                = "MyUniqueWebAppName"
  location            = "West Europe"
  resource_group_name = "example-resources"
  app_service_plan_id = data.azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id


  connection_string {
    name  = "myConectionString"
    type  = "SQLServer"
    value = "Server=tcp:mysqlservername123.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
  }
  backup {
    name                = "MyBackupName"
    enabled             = true
    storage_account_url = "https://storageaccountnameqwetih.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?sp=r&st=2022-08-31T09:49:17Z&se=2022-08-31T17:49:17Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=2JwQ%xx%2B%2xxB5xxxxFZxxVyAadjxxV8%3D"
    schedule {
      frequency_interval       = 30
      frequency_unit           = "Day"
      keep_at_least_one_backup = true
      retention_period_in_days = 10
      start_time               = "2022-08-31T07:11:56.52Z"
    }
  }
}
```

But when I run it i got a error `A resource with the ID ........ /MyUniqueWebAppName" already exists - to be managed via Terraform this resource needs to be imported into the State.`
How in terraform can I point to an existing `Azure APP Service` and add a backup with the same schedule as I did in my template?

Comment: btw, please(!) do not keep secrets like your connection string in clear text in your Terraform file!! use something like Key Vault referenced app settings https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-key-vault-references?tabs=azure-cli
Or even better, use AAD-based auth to connect to SQL with MSI of the app service

Answer (score 1):

Before you can modify your existing resources with TF, you must [import](https://www.terraform.io/cli/import) into the terraform state. For this you use [import command](https://www.terraform.io/cli/commands/import).

Answer (score 0):

```
    data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
         name = "<give rg name existing one>"
}

    data "azurerm_app_service_plan" "example" {
      name                = "MyUniqueServicePlan"
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
    }
    
    
   data "azurerm_app_service" "example" {
      name                = "MyUniqueWebAppName"
      location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
      resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
      app_service_plan_id = data.azurerm_app_service_plan.example.id
    
    
      connection_string {
        name  = "myConectionString"
        type  = "SQLServer"
        value = "Server=tcp:mysqlservername123.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=MyDatabaseName;Persist Security Info=False;User ID=xxx;Password=xxxxxx;MultipleActiveResultSets=False;Encrypt=True;TrustServerCertificate=False;Connection Timeout=30;"
      }
      backup {
        name                = "MyBackupName"
        enabled             = true
        storage_account_url = "https://storageaccountnameqwetih.blob.core.windows.net/mycontainer?sp=r&st=2022-08-31T09:49:17Z&se=2022-08-31T17:49:17Z&spr=https&sv=2021-06-08&sr=c&sig=2JwQ%xx%2B%2xxB5xxxxFZxxVyAadjxxV8%3D"
        schedule {
          frequency_interval       = 30
          frequency_unit           = "Day"
          keep_at_least_one_backup = true
          retention_period_in_days = 10
          start_time               = "2022-08-31T07:11:56.52Z"
        }
      }
    }
```

No need to use import command , use this code for your reference
just give rg name existing one in resources group block